# Why are my lists not rotating in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, set

```
    import java.util.*;
public class RotateList {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<List<Integer>> copies = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
        int size = list.size();
        Set<List<Integer>> set  = new HashSet<>();
        while(size > 0)
        {
            copies.add(list);
            size--;
        }
        size = list.size();
        System.out.println("Copies Before:");
        System.out.println(copies);

        for(int i = 0; i < copies.size();i++)
        {

            Collections.rotate(copies.get(i), i+1);

        }
        System.out.println("Copies after:");
        System.out.println(copies);
        }
```

}

The output is:

> Copies Before: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]] 
>   Copies after: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

I don't know where I'm going wrong with this.

Comment: All the elements in your `copies` are identical, how would you know if they're rotated or not? And total rotations are `1+2+3=6` which brings all elements to their original place.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are adding the same list 3 times. When you rotate one of them, you rotate all of them.

You must create 3 separate lists.

```
List<List<Integer>> copies = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    copies.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3)));
}

System.out.println("Copies Before:");
System.out.println(copies);

for (int i = 0; i < copies.size(); i++) {
    Collections.rotate(copies.get(i), i + 1);
}

System.out.println("Copies after:");
System.out.println(copies);
```

Output:

```
Copies Before:
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
Copies after:
[[3, 1, 2], [2, 3, 1], [1, 2, 3]]
```